# Why Does an Array in iOS 4.0 Appear as __NSArrayI (And How Do I Match it)?

Tags: iphone, ios4

An object which used to identify itself as NSCFArray under previous iPhoneOSes now seems to identify itself as __NSArrayI under devices running iOS 4.0.

Any idea what's up with this? I can't find it in any documentation.

In addition, it doesn't match "[NSArray class]".

It should be a simple array. It's defined like this:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         thisPlayerName,@"name",
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:[myTable.visiblePlayer.number intValue]],@"number",
                         playerCountArray,@"players",
                         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"easy",@"medium",@"hard",nil],@"opponent difficulty",
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:[cardDecks getOptionBoolForKey:@"seeMoney"]],@"see money",
                         [cardDecks gameSpeedOptions],@"computer turn speed",
                         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aqua",@"green",@"orange",@"purple",@"red",nil],@"player color",
                         nil];
```

Then fed into another dictionary like this:

```
    myRecord = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    [myRecord addEntriesFromDictionary:newDictionary];
```

Everything else has classes like I'd expect: NSCFString, NSCFNumber, NSCFBoolean, but not the arrays, and I can't figure out how to match it.

Comment: [NSArray class] wouldn't return NSCFArray anyway. It should just return NSArray. Are you getting __NSArrayI as a result from calling class on your array instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Why does it appear like that?** Because we can't trust the internal names of classes from one release to another.

**How to match it?** Don't try and match the name of the class or to equivalate the class. Just use isKindOfClass: which will match against a class and its subclasses, and does the right thing for weird variants like this.

For example:

```
    } else if ([thisValue isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
```

Note that you're sending the isKindOfClass: message to an object, *not* to [object class]!